# Comparing the definition of a cone from Wikipedia and from Marty Arkowitz.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homotopy-theory, fibration, cofibrations

Here is the definition of a cone (on pg.76) from "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" by Martin Arkowitz:

> [image]

But the definition of Wikipedia here [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)#:~:text=In%20topology%2C%20especially%20algebraic%20topology,the%20cylinder%20to%20a%20point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)#:%7E:text=In%20topology%2C%20especially%20algebraic%20topology,the%20cylinder%20to%20a%20point). is just this $$(A \times I)/(A \times \{0\}).$$

My question is:

What does it mean the union by $\{*\} \times I$ in Arkowitz book? Could anyone explain that for me, please?

Comment: Arkowitz is talking about pointed spaces, whereas Wikipedia is talking about unpointed spaces. $*$ is the distinguished point of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the case where $A$ is a circle with a particular point on it (called $\star$) marked red. Extrude it to get $A \times I$, a cylinder that now has a red stripe, $\star \times I$, with the original circle at one end, namely $S^1 \times \{0\}.$ Now collapse that end to a point, and you get a cone, with its tip at the $0$ end and its "base circle" at the $1$ end. And it's got a red stripe as one of the lateral generators.

Arkowitz is proposing to contract that red stripe to a point to get a homotopy-equivalent space, and calling THAT the "cone on $A$". I suppose that doing so makes certain inclusions become nicer maps in some way, so it's just a trick to simplify some later theorem-statements or proofs. But the two spaces are homotopy equivalent, which means that for a homotopy-theory book, they're pretty much the same.

**Post-comment addition**

The reduced cone is topologically a disk. But suppose that you DOUBLED this process, i.e., made two cones (without shrinking the stripe) and glued them along the circular boundary of each one. You'd get something like a sphere with the two stripes together forming a line of longitude. If you now contract that line of longitude, you get a single "basepoint" for your new sphere, and you've essentially built the "suspension" operation (which will come up a *lot*) in a way that preserves basepoints really naturally,

Comment: Is the red strip **only** also collapsed to a point ? this is why we mod out by it in the cone definition?

Comment: The definition says that the circle at the $0$ end, AND the red stripe ($\star \times I$) are all collectively collapsed to a single point. All the other strips, i.e., $(P \times I)$ for $P \in S^1$ and $P \ne \star$, are left untouched. If you think of the cone as one of those cheap paper water-cups that are provided at some water coolers, you can imagine simply cutting along one of the generators...or to make things a little prettier, cutting a soft V-shaped notch from the rim down to the tip. From almost all points of the "V" to the tip you have a line-segment (something like $I$);

Comment: from the center point of the $V$ to the tip....well.those are the same point, so you have just a single point (the new "basepoint") rather than a whole line segment.

Comment: The resulting "reduced cone" is topologically just a disk but you probably don't want to think of it that way,

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)#Reduced_cone) of that page, which is specifically in the case of a pointed space. Does Arkowitz use $\{*\}$ to refer to a generic basepoint?

Comment: Yes. So is the reduced cone is just a circle?